# PHP shell_exec($cmd) stops inmediatelly

Tags: php, bash, video-streaming

I try to run a shell script from a web browser that turns on a camera with mjpg_streamer. The problem is that it stops in less than a second. I've tried daemonizing using `$command = nohup ./videoOn.sh &` and `>/dev/null &` but it returns the same result.

It works when I execute it from bash directly with `php video.php`

This is the php file.

```
    //video.php
    <?php
       $command = './videoOn.sh';
       exec($command);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a `.sh` to do this job, simply do it like this:

- Find the environment php by this command:

  ```
  which php
  ```

it will return you the path e.g. `/var/path/php` and use it in the exec directly as

```
$command = "/var/path/php video.php"
exec($command);
```

Comment: It can't be possible, videoOn.sh is a script neccesary to turn on the camera